# How to setup DNS records for webmail of my domain in digital ocean?

Tags: cpanel, digital-ocean, cdn

I moved to Digital ocean droplets as a hosting provider for my site a few months ago.  Earlier I was using shared hosting. What DNS entry I should do in droplet settings to make sure that webmail.mydomain.com points to older shared hosting where I have set up my webmail in CPanel and Roundcube client.

Currently, my name server is set up on quik.CDN and Droplet as hosting for the main domain.